# Debugging in Visual Studio 2019 doesn't work if I create a dotnet console app via PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I have dotnet version 5.0.101.  When I create a new console application in PowerShell using the command:

```
dotnet new console
```

and open that file in Visual Studio 2019, if I try to start debugging, this error is always thrown:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

If I open the same file in Visual Studio Code, debugging works.

If I just build the file from Visual Studio 2019, it builds successfully and I can run the application.

If I create a new console application through Visual Studio, debugging works.

Is a special file that isn't created when I create a new console app through PowerShell that would otherwise be created through Visual Studio? I'm not sure why just the debugger can't run, seems to be an error with versions??